# CSS applying styles selectively

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a editor page that allows you to preview HTML files.

The problem is however that the editors styles are being inherited by the previewed HTML file e.g.:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="top">
        Editing HTML page - page1.html
    </div>
</div>

<div class="preview">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="top">
            Page 1.html
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that a work around would be to use an IFRAME, however I would prefer not to do this as I will be allowing drag and drop capabilities.

A CSS solution would be great, I did have the idea of using jquery to add a class to every item in the 'preview' area and using the following CSS for the editor page:

```
.header:not(.preview) {
    background-color:#000;
}

.top:not(.preview) {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This however seems a bit of a hacky solution and it would be great if there was a neater solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you ultimately need to use `not`, you should *invert* your selectors:

```
:not(.preview) > .header { background-color:#000; }
:not(.preview) > .header .top { color: #fff; }
```

But it's better to design selectors in some other way